# Rust - create filter predicate as function

Tags: rust, closures

I want to create a function which returns a predicate.

I have an vector and I want to filter based on character a specific character. My code:

```rust
let n = 0; // Irrelevant. This will change
co2 = co2
  .into_iter()
  .filter(|&binary| binary.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().get(n).unwrap() == &'1')
  .collect();
```

I have a couple of characters I want to match. My intention was to create a function like this:

```rust
fn create_predicate(character: char, n: usize) -> impl FnMut(&str) {
    move |x: &str| {
        return x.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().get(n).unwrap() == &character;
    }
}

co2 = co2.filter(create_predicate('q', n));
```

This wont work, but I would like to make it look something like that

So I want to have a function that creates a predicate which I can use in my filter. How can I do that?

Comment: Side note: You don't want `Iterator::filter()` here. You actually want `Vec::retain()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @SvenMarnach. I assumed there was a better way than doing what I did. This will mutate the vector. In my usecase, its alright. but how are you gonna do if you want it to be immutable?

Comment: The problem with `co2 = co2.filter(...)` is that the left-hand side has a different type than the right-hand side, so this doesn't work in a statically typed language. If you iteratively want to use `filter()` for a dynamic number of times, you need to simulate dynamic typing. You could try using the type `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = ...>>`, and create a new box in each iteration.

Comment: You can also always collect into a new `Vec` once and then modify that vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give a complete answer without a full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you can get close with two changes to your code:

- The predicate must return `bool` if you want to use it in `filter`.
- Possibly, the predicate must take `&&str`.

Working example:

```
fn create_predicate(character: char, n: usize) -> impl FnMut(&&str) -> bool {
    move |x: &&str| {
        return x.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().get(n).unwrap() == &character;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let co2 = [ "azerty", "foo", "bar" ];
    let co2 = co2.iter().copied().filter(create_predicate('q', 1));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9400938885a5bcc64b894eebd0891089)

Comment: Sorry bout my example. Is there a reason why to run `copied()` before filtering?

Comment: Without `copied` the predicate would need to take `&&&str` but otherwise it should work.